# Expected a value of type 'string' but got one of type 'int' - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I have a function that returns a `String`, but when I call this function, the app screen goes red and I get this error: `Expected a value of type 'string' but got one of type 'int'`.

Here is my function that returns a `String`:

```
  checkProportion(String predominantGamete, String resultado) {
    var countBrown = 0;
    var countBlack = 0;
    var countWhite = 0;
    var proportionCamundongo =
        'Proporção: ${countBrown}:${countBlack}:${countWhite}';

    if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
        resultado.contains('A') &&
        resultado.contains('P')) {
      return countBrown += 1;
    } else if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
        resultado.contains('A') &&
        resultado.contains('pp')) {
      return countBlack += 1;
    } else if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
        resultado.contains('aa')) {
      return countWhite += 1;
    }
    return proportionCamundongo;
  }
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          checkProportion(widget.predominant, widget.result),
        ),
      ),
```

How to solve this error?

Here is an image that shows the colors of each result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are returning early, not breaking the if statement, when you do something like `return countBrown += 1;`;

Try incrementing the counters, then using string interpolation to display the value:

```
String checkProportion(String predominantGamete, String resultado) {
  int countBrown = 0;
  int countBlack = 0;
  int countWhite = 0;

  if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
    resultado.contains('A') &&
    resultado.contains('P')) {
    countBrown += 1;
  } else if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
    resultado.contains('A') &&
    resultado.contains('pp')) {
    countBlack += 1;
  } else if (predominantGamete == 'recessiva_aa' &&
    resultado.contains('aa')) {
    countWhite += 1;
  }
  return 'Proporção: ${countBrown}:${countBlack}:${countWhite}';
}
```

I'd also recommend specifing the return type of the function (`String`), using the correct types for counters (`int`). That will help your compiler catch the issues as well.

Comment: This worked well, but I wonder if there is a way to turn each if statement into for loops with the same conditions. It didn't give me the result that I wanted, it just counted one time and that's it. Could you give me a hand on that?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't my best work, and there is probably a better way to check for if a string contains all occurrence of multiple substrings, but here you go:

```
bool isColorContained(String resultado, Set<String> requirements) {
  for(String requirement in requirements) {
      if (!resultado.contains(requirement)) {
        return false;            
      }
    }
  return true;
}
```

```
String checkProportion(String predominantGamete, String resultado) {         
  Map<ColorType, Set<String>> colorType = {
    ColorType.brown: {'A', 'P'},
    ColorType.black: {'A', 'pp'},
    ColorType.white: {'aa'},
  };
  Map<ColorType, int> colorTypeCount = {
    ColorType.brown: 0,
    ColorType.black: 0,
    ColorType.white: 0,
  };
  for(MapEntry<ColorType, Set<String>> entry in colorType.entries )  {
    if(predominantGamete != 'recessiva_aa') continue;
    bool contained = isColorContained(resultado, entry.value);        
    if(contained) {
      int count = colorTypeCount[entry.key] ?? 0;
      colorTypeCount[entry.key] = count + 1;
    }      
  }
  return 'Proporção: ${colorTypeCount[ColorType.brown]}:${colorTypeCount[ColorType.black]}:${colorTypeCount[ColorType.white]}';
}
```

Also, declare the `ColorType` enum:

```
enum ColorType {
  brown, black, white
}
```

This will scale with as many colors and requirements you have, by adding to the `ColorType` enum, the `colorType` map, and the `colorTypeCount` map.

Comment: Here it gives an error in ColorType `The name 'ColorType' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
Try correcting the name to an existing type, or defining a type named 'ColorType'.`

Comment: Make sure you define the `ColorType` (its the enum after the function). You'll want to do this outside of any functions or classes.

Comment: Also, I cleaned up that function a little, by adding the `isColorContained` function

Comment: I'm sorry to ask that but, how would I define the ColorType? I'm kinda stuck

Comment: Check out this on dart enums: 

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types

bottom line, is that you just need to add this code, before or after your class or definition (it cannot be declared _inside_ a class or function):

```enum ColorType {
  brown, black, white
}```

Comment: Although it's working, the output is Proportion: 1:0:0. In other words, it's just counting one time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237858/discussion-between-jared-anderton-and-bilbo-bo).

Comment: I've just added an image to the question so you can visualize it better. The colors change, they are not fixed in just one place, that's why I thought about using a loop